# Which syntax to use for better performance and resource utilisation

Tags: java, android, performance, coding-style

After reading several articles on how to fine-tuning my code, I found out that the way we are declaring objects and variables could drasticatly impact the performance of our application.  This is more and more important as time constraint is now an integral part of some aspects of the Android platform (e.g. result must be provided within 5 sec for some operations).

Now, I found the following code in one of my fragment class (perfectly functional):

```
Activity myA = getActivity();
if(myA instanceof MainActivity) {
((MainActivity) myA).doNext();
}
```

Knowing that objects creation/destruction and ressources allocation are some of the factors contributing to drain-out the device’s batteries, I had in mind to rewrite my code to:

```
if(getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
((MainActivity ) getActivity()).doNext();
}
```

From a functional perspective, both codes are delivering the same results.  However, what is the most suitable approach?  I’m asking because I see pros and cons to both approach and I’m unable to find the appropriate way to evaluate the performance and I’m also not clear on which counters (memory usage, function' speed, used CPU cycles, etc) the evaluation should be performed.

Thanks for your contribution in advance.

Comment: Object creation/destruction happens thousands of times per second across the device; are you sure it's worth trying to optimize it at this level?

Comment: I concur that my example is a very basic one and I will most likely not invest to much time on the optimization of this specific code.  My interest is more from a global perspective as we are doing such type of assignation and/or object construction so often, then at the end, the overall performance could be affected.  By performance, I’m not only considering speed, but also impact on external resources (battery, etc...)

Comment: @DominicHarvey From a global perspective, you absolutely must use a profiler as it is the only tool that will actually tell you anything about a global perspective.

Comment: @DominicHarvey: Also, in this specific case, I'd try to use polymorphism instead of `instanceof` checks. I.e. have `getActivity()` return not a builtin Android type, but an interface (`IMyActivity`) or whatever that already has the method `doNext()`. If you need `getActivity()` to return a class not in your codebase you could create an adapter where that method does nothing, and it'd probably still be cheaper than doing `instanceof`. (Regardless of what you've read, any decent Java runtime will heavily optimise creating very short lived throwaway objects.)

Comment: Or do something else entirely, it's hard to suggest a design without knowing what `getActivity()` does. And last but not least: if `getActivity()` simply gets a field, odds are JIT would inline it anyway and the two code samples you posted would end up being completely identical. (The JIT is reason #bajillion why you should use a profiler or at the very least measure wall clock time - the translation between code constructs and instructions executed is neither straightforward nor deterministic, therefore reasoning about the former is of only marginal use.)

Comment: As for optimising for battery use, you're probably not getting any precise numbers. That said, battery use should at least roughly correlate to CPU, GPU, and network use, so you should see improvements by optimising those. (That said, the backlighting will [match and/or utterly dominate](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix10/tech/full_papers/Carroll.pdf) those, so if you want your app to not drain the battery design it so people don't really need to look at it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing what could be a performance bottleneck is a very common waste of time.  You have to measure what makes a difference to your whole program instead of guessing.

> Knowing that objects creation/destruction is one of the factors

Creating a few objects doesn't matter.  Creating too many object matters.  How much is too much and which objects are created most is something you should use a profiler to determine.

> From a functional perspective, both codes are delivering the same results. However, what is the most suitable approach?

Whatever you feel is the simplest.  I believe that adding the method `doNext` to the class which `getActivity()` returns would be best so you can write the following is clearest.

```
getActivity().doNext();
```

> I’m unable to find the appropriate way to evaluate the performance

Use a CPU and memory profiler, or write a performance test for different components of your system.

> which counters (memory usage, function' speed, used CPU cycles, etc) the evaluation should be performed.

If you can't use a profiler, I would start simple with elapse time. i.e. System.nanoTime(). This is usually all you need.

Comment: Many thanks Peter.  Do you have any good profile to recommand?  I'm using Eclips on Window 7.

Comment: I would start with VisualVM which is free and comes with the JDK.  I use YourKit for which you can get an eval license (2 weeks free ??) which is normally long enough to fix your problem. ;)

Comment: I have been performance tuning systems for more than 15 years I am still surprised how often something simple, which you would never think of, is making a difference to your performance.  I have interviewed senior developers from hedge funds who spent months tuning their systems while missing something much more significant because they didn't consider the whole system.

Answer (score 3):

Declaration/assignment is not object creation in Java. It only puts reference on the stack. First one is clearer and possibly faster (`getActivity` is called only once).

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the what does `getActivity()` do. The difference of the 2 segments of code is that the second one calls the function 2 time. The function call by itself is very fast, but what the function is doing may not be fast.

If you are not sure what is this function you can just use the first one, although the second one is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If `getActiviy` does not create new objects, instead it returns created objects depending on some criteria and is not computation intensive then the second approach is better. However, if every time you call `getActivity` you create new objects and/or if `getActivity` is computation intensive first approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

If getActivity() returns a different object every time you call it, the second version is *incorrect,* and if it doesn't, the second version is merely redundant. Neither is a reason to prefer the second version, and there aren't any other reasons to prefer it either. As Pater Lawrey says, don't waste time trying to guess where your performance problems are. Measure.